# ¿Cómo hago un icono de notificación permanente que me lleve a mi aplicación? Android

Tags: android, activity

Lo que quiero hacer es que al iniciar un *Activity* en concreto de mi aplicación, me cree ese icono de notificación que este presente mientras la *Activity* esta en ejecución. El pulsar la notificación me devolverá a mi *App*.

He usado esto de la *API*:

```
//ICONO DE NOTIFICACION
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("B-TRACKER")
                    .setContentText("Abrir aplicación")
                    .setOngoing(true);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
    resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MapsActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Todo eso está en el método *OnCreate*, pero no me lleva a mi *App*

Comment: Agrego el código de ejemplo como respuesta cuando lo permita, pero mientras, explico aquí para solucionar lo que pides.
En tu builder, agrega .setOngoing(true) eso evita que la notificación pueda cerrarse, pero no olvides cerrarla tu cuando el usuario salga de la aplicación. Para que abra la activity, es únicamente pasar el intent a el PendingIntent y este asignarlo a el Builder. Respecto al Intent, agrega flags para evitar que se abra la misma activity al pulsar la notificación.
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dejo código de ejemplo de lo que pides:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
.setContentTitle("B-TRACKER")
.setOngoing(true) // <-- esto hace la notificacion permanente
.setContentText("Abrir aplicación");


 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class); //<-- La clase que se abrira al hacer click en la notificacion
 notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); 

 PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0); //<-- creas un Pending intent con lo asignado en el intent
 mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent); //<-- agregas el pendindIntent a tu notificacion
 NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

 mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build()); // <-- muestras la notificacion
```

Con **.setOngoing(true)** haces tu notificación persistente, por otro lado te he agregado los flags **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP** y **FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP**. Estos harán que si al pulsar en la notificación ya estaba la Activity previamente creada, abrirá la misma, y en caso de no estarlo, la creara.

No olvides eliminar la notificación cuando el usuario salga de la aplicación.

Edito:
Como dices en tu comentario, agregar los siguientes flags si no se comporta de manera correcta:

```
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Lo he probado y me crea la notificación, pero al pulsarla parece que rompe por algún sitio, porque se me cierra la Activity, y la notificación persiste ahí, le vuelvo a dar y hace un amago de abrirme la aplicación pero sin resultado. El caso es que me funcionaba antes, pero al poner un NavigationBottomMenu ya me ha dejado de funcionar, no se si tendrá algo que ver.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el Log para ver que sucede? El código en mi ejemplo lo uso actualmente en una aplicación y funciona correctamente. No obstante, ¿tienes modificado el launchMode en tu archivo de manifiesto? Pero seguramente sea cosa como dices del navigation que has agregado, tal vez lo instancies en otra clase o alguna cosa similar y el error sea algun NullPointerException

Comment: Vale, creo que di con el problema, Tengo un MainActivity que con un boton accedo a la Activity en cuestión que quiero que me restablezca al pulsar la notificación. Le paso un putExtra, y parece que rompe por eso. Se lo he quitado, y ahora si que me funciona pero no como esperaba, me abre otra actividad y no restablece la que tenia abierta.

Comment: agrega en tu AndroidManifest:  android:launchMode="singleTask" dentro de <application...

Comment: Se me comporta igual, me abre una nueva actividad. En el Activity tengo puesto _android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"_

Comment: Si usas el codigo puesto como ejemplo, deberia de abrirte unicamente una Activity, no obstante lo revisare y editare en caso de ser necesario algun cambio por si me he pasado algo por alto.

Comment: Investigando un poco tenia que añadir mas flags:
_notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);_
Ahora si que se comporta como yo quiero, edita tu respuesta para ayudar a otra gente que tenga el mismo problema